# How to show top view post from selected category

Tags: wordpress

I've two category in wordpress. for example cat=4 & cat = 5. I want to show top view posts from cat=4. How can i do this ? I am using the following codes to show my top view post.

**function.php**

```
<?php

 function popularPosts($num) {
global $wpdb;

$posts = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT comment_count, ID, post_title FROM $wpdb->posts ORDER BY comment_count DESC LIMIT 0 , $num");

foreach ($posts as $post) {
    setup_postdata($post);
    $id = $post->ID;
    $title = $post->post_title;
    $count = $post->comment_count;

    if ($count != 0) {
        $popular .= '<li>';
        $popular .= '<a href="' . get_permalink($id) . '" title="' . $title . '">'.get_the_post_thumbnail($id) ."<br/>". $title . '</a> ';
        $popular .= '</li>';
    }
}
return $popular;
 }

  ?>
```

sidebar.php

```
 <div class="popular">
   <h3>Most Popular Posts</h3>

     <?php echo popularPosts(3); ?>

 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As of now you are basing your view count on the amount of commentaries so this doesn't really represent post view.. What you could do is have meta_value being updated on page loads. You could also use a plugin such as

> https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-popular-posts/

which already records that information, then fetch the information from their structure.